# How to get userinfo with Microsoft OAuth after successfully authenticated

Tags: java, servlets, oauth, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

My applications should login with Microsoft account (OAuth Provider). I got stuck to get user info after successfully authenticated by using following URL
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=SCOPES&response_type=code&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL
 Can any one please help me to get user-info? Is there any library that I need to include for that ?
I'm getting authenticated code but I don't know how use ? I'm working with JAVA

Comment: your link isn't working for me - does anyone else has this problem?

Comment: @Martin Frank : Thanks for your response. Yeah the link won't work because I didn't give scope,client_id and redirect_uri. scope=wl.basic & client_id is my api key which I can't share here and redirect_uri is just url which we want to redirect to particular servlet where we need to get user info. ie like http://localhost:8080/callback. Help me if any one knows about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The userinfo endpoint is `https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me`. Before you call it you need to exchange the `code` for a `token`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I'm exchanging code for token with `https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf` And I followed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx  site.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling here.

**OpenID discovery URL**: `https://login.live.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Microsoft doesn't provide `userinfo_endpoint` in the service configuration json

**UserInfo URL** : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

Make a GET request to this url with header containing `access_token` that you got after exchanging `auth_code`

Key: `Authorization`

Value: `Bearer <access_token>`